# my iad is still being displayed when I change from one screen to the next

Tags: ios, iad

I have successfully implemented iAd into my App just this past week, but when my fill rate was very low I looked into it, and I realize I have a problem.  My iAd banner is correclty displayed on the first screen the user sees, and that is the only screen on which the banner ad is displayed by my design.  I setup a singleton class to manage the ads, and I'm expanding it to display on additional screens in an upcoming release.  However, when I push another view controller to the front that doesn't display ads, my iAd delegate methods:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
- (void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
```

are still being called every 3 minutes as though the view is active.

Is there a way to temporarily disable iAd from trying to refresh?  thanks in advance.

Comment: Does hiding the iAd view using `UIView`'s `-setHidden:` work?

Comment: That doesn't work either - after 3 minutes the ad is refreshed, and the delegate routines are called.  I guess I could release the ADBannerView object, but I want to be able to show the same ad if they come back before the 3 minute timer, so I don't want to do that just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not showing ads on all of the pages, I create/release the ad object when my view controller that is showing ads is displayed/not-displayed (and set the delegate to nil), and this prevents any ads/delegate functions on view controllers that are not currently displayed from being displayed.